# What is it saved in the model of sklearn bayesian classifier

Tags: math, scikit-learn, bayesian

I believe that a Bayesian classifier is based on statistical model. But after training a Bayesian model, I can save it and do not need the training dataset to predict the test data. For example, if I build a bayesian model by

[image: Bayesian Model]
y - labels,X-samples

Can I take the model as a equation like this?

[image: Equation]

If so, how can I extract the weights and bias? and what is the new formula looks like?If not, what is the new equation like?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to find some materials about how to use intercept_ and coef_, or how to re-build the model(extract the parameters in model). But I cannot find any materials to solve my problem. Could you help me with the problem? Or give me some materials about it? I really appreciate it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn-naive-bayes-multinomialnb), a trained classifier has two attributes, `intercept_` and `coef_` which are useful if you want to interpret the NBC as a linear model.